# How to make the terminal auto-complete from the command history?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut, history, auto-complete

In Linux, I had managed to set up the terminal in such a way that if I type part of a command and press the arrow key 'up', it would auto-complete with the last command that started with what I had typed.

I tried to do the same on MacOS following the instructions on [this MacWorld article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031026174236860), but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to set this up on a Mac?

Comment: Related: [Command-line completion from command history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/command-line-completion-from-command-history)

Comment: It's better to use ctrl+r to search your command history, that way you don't have to even remember the command name. It has sped up my terminal usage by many times. Highly recommended. Plus, I recommend the Z Shell and: http://ohmyz.sh

Comment: In the end I installed Fish shell, which autocompletes from the history as you type, so you only have to press the right arrow to complete the command.

Comment: When asking terminal or shell questions, please _provide your shell type_ (Bash, Zsh, Fish) since they behave differently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may use reverse-search.
Just press ctrl+R and start typing your command, and then just press Enter.

Comment: I fail to see how this is not infinitely worse that the Page-Up / Page-Down solution in Linux.

Answer (score 7):

#### Bind key to `history-search`

For searching lines  **starting with** the typed, as you read in [Macworld article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031026174236860), you can add the keybindings, for example:

- <kbd>Up</kbd> key bound to `history-search-backward`
- <kbd>Down</kbd> key bound to `history-search-forward`

To add them permanent edit your `~/.inputrc` like this

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Same can be achieved using the `bind` command in your `~/.bashrc` by pasting above lines within *single-quotes* (`'`) as argument:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

**Note**: for both settings to take effect you have to restart terminal !

#### Alternative: use built-in history search shortcuts

You can use [*Reverse History Search* in Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html) as explained in the question [Searching your command history on macOS terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780746/searching-your-command-history-on-macos-terminal).

Following shortcuts allow to search **parts of commands** in your Bash command *history*:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> backwards
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> forwards

#### Tag typed commands for easy search later

Wouldn't above reverse-search be useful if you can set **easy to remember keywords**?

To leverage **partial** history search you can also append commands with comments, e.g. typing a command for later use:

```
ls -l *.sh # list scripts
```

The added comment (starting with `#`) allows to search for `list scripts` since the comment  is recorded in history.

Comment: This applies to _bash_ (default shell for macOS Mojave and earlier) and with some modifications also to _zsh_ ([default shell starting with macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050))

Answer (score 5):

You may refer to auto suggestion.

And for zsh user, [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) will be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the inclusion of the zsh-autosuggestions, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: Finally, I turn to Fish shell. It's really worth a try!

Comment: Will EVERY bash script run flawlessly on Fish shell?

Comment: For ZSH style suggestions you can use `ble.sh`, see https://superuser.com/a/1644033/322610

Answer (score 2):

In order to get up/down arrow history search behavior to work on MacOS Monterey, I had to put the bindings in my `.zshrc` file.

I used this flavor of history-search behavior:

```
bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward
```

It will match command strings exactly, even after a space is typed. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/zsh-search-history-on-up-and-down-keys) for more discussion.

Comment: What is the "this" you are referring to in the first sentence? If your answer doesn't stand on its own but is primarily an extension of an existing one, an edit of that answer might be more useful.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to clarify that "this" refers to the behavior being sought in the original question.